# mysql select data for each value in array

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a list:

`destinations = test_task.destination_list()` - which is a list of strings, containing a countries names assigned to current test_task object.

And i have a table **CDR** with fields:

```
id(pk)
number(charfield)
area(charfield).
```

I need to select 3 random numbers from CDR table where area=destination for each destination.

Can i do it using only one select? 
Or do i need to make a loop for each destination? 
Which is a right way?

Comment: can u give example or give what u tried in sqlfiddle?

Comment: I think you cannot do that without a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I mentioned in the comments I think there is no viable ways to do that with a single query.
If you use a loop you can combine [random ordering](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by-fields), [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) and "[in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)" operator for querysets.

```
final_list = []
for destination in destinations:
    final_list += YourCDRModel.objects.filter(area__in=destination).values_list('number', flat=True).order_by('?')[0:3]
```

be aware that this query may be slow as documented in the *order_by* docs, and may become even more slow if the number of destinations is high.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is for  sure make a loop and query per each destination ordering by rand()  and having limit to 3.
If you do not want  to  do  this and you wanto to perform  a single query mysql is  not able to give you  back 3 result per row by using a single query. You are obligate  to ask for the full  return and put the logic for  reduce the number of result in our code. You can run query like "SELECT * FROM CDR WHERE IN ( ? ,? ... ) ORDER BY RAND() and that loop in to the result until you got 3 row  per  type.

If your array of destination is not too big i will suggest to loop into the destination and query per each destination rather  than select all the possible result and loop into it with the code.